# ext js 4 using module design pattern in controller

Tags: design-patterns, module, extjs4

Is it a recommended practice to use a module pattern when developing controllers in ext js?

I believe by doing so we achieve the following:

> 1) abstracting out the framework in use. Business logic is implemented
>   in the module. Module doesn't (at least shouldn't), know anything
>   about framework functionality.
>
> 2) Exposing dependences.  Framework should supply the module with
>   required data. Module should only operate on that knowledge.
>
> 3) Easier unit testing.  Your tests don't depend on framework
>   knowledge. You only test business scenarios.

The module pattern was very popular in sencha tutorials and examples in versions prior to Ext is 4.0, but I couldn't find any reference to it in recent tutorials.

Has anything changed? Am I missing something?
Do you use such a practice?

Thank you for your input

Edit:

Below is a code for the master/detail controller.
It loads selected row into the detail form and then fires 'mycustomevent'.
It also prevents grid row selection if the data in the form is invalid.

I added 2 variants of code.
1) Simple ext js implementation.
2) Same implementation with use of model pattern.

=== Ext Js Controller===

```
Ext.define('Patterns.controller.MoviesMasterDetail', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views : ['Patterns.view.Movies',
        'Patterns.view.Detail'],
    refs : [{
            ref : 'Detail',
            selector : 'detail'
        }
    ],
    init : function () {
        this.control({
            'movies' : {
                beforeselect : this.onBeforeSelect,
                selectionchange : this.onMovieSelected
            },          
            'detail' : {
                'mycustomevent' : this.onMyCustomEventWithArgs
            }           
        });
    },
    onMyCustomEventWithArgs: function(arg)  {
        alert(arg);
    },
    onBeforeSelect : function () {
        var detailForm = this.getDetail().getForm(),
            hasRecord = detailForm.getRecord() != null;
        if(hasRecord) {
            return detailForm.isValid();            
        }

        return true;
    },
    onMovieSelected : function (thisSelectionModel, selected, eOpts) { 
        var detail = this.getDetail();
        var detailForm = detail.getForm();
        var rec = selected[0];
        rec.data['descr'] = 'modified';
        detailForm.loadRecord(selected[0]);
        detail.fireMyEvent('from controller');
    }
});
```

=== Ext Js Controller with module pattern ===

```
Ext.define('Patterns.controller.MoviesMasterDetailModule', {
    extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    views : ['Patterns.view.Movies',
        'Patterns.view.Detail'],
    refs : [{
            ref : 'Detail',
            selector : 'detail'
        }
    ],
    init : function () {
        this.control({
            'movies' : {
                beforeselect : this.onBeforeSelect,
                selectionchange : this.onMovieSelected
            },
            'detail' : {
                'mycustomevent' : this.onMyCustomEventWithArgs
            }
        });
    },
    onMyCustomEventWithArgs: function(arg)  {
        alert(arg);
    },
    onBeforeSelect : function () {

        var me = this,
            detailForm = me.getDetail().getForm(),
            formRecord = detailForm.getRecord();
            module = new Module();

            return module.onBeforeSelect(formRecord, detailForm.isValid, detailForm);
    },
    onMovieSelected : function (thisSelectionModel, selected, eOpts) {
        var detail = this.getDetail();
        var detailForm = this.getDetail().getForm(),
        module = new Module()
        recToLoad = selected[0];

        var loadRecordTupple = {
                    fn: detailForm.loadRecord, 
                    scope: detailForm
                    };


        var fireEventTupple = {
                    fn: detail.fireMyEvent, 
                    scope: detail
                    };

        module.modifyRecord(recToLoad, loadRecordTupple, fireEventTupple );
    }
});
```

=== Module implementation ===

```
function Module()
{
    var onBeforeSelect = function(selectedRecord, validationFunc, caller){
        if(!selectedRecord){
            return true;
        }

        return validationFunc.apply(caller);
    };

    var modifyRecord = function(dataToLoad, loadTupple, fireEventTupple, caller){
        dataToLoad.data['descr'] = "modified";

        loadTupple.fn.apply(loadTupple.scope, [dataToLoad]);
        fireEventTupple.fn.apply(fireEventTupple.scope, ["from module"]);
    }

    this.onBeforeSelect = onBeforeSelect;
    this.modifyRecord = modifyRecord;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DanielS,
**You asked:**
"Is it a recommended practice to use a module pattern when developing controllers in ext js?"
My Answer is completely, yes. Although, ExtJs doesn't suggest it in writings anywhere I've seen.

I did a presentation at a Javascript Meetup in Denver, CO showing the usage of the library I wrote that enforces a Modular (constructor driven) MVC Design Pattern.

At that presentation was one of the lead developers of the ExtJs Architect application. He told me (off the record) that the use of Modular MVC design pattern is where ExtJs is going. So maybe we will see this design pattern promoted in the ExtJs 5 documentation. But as of today, ExtJs still suggests putting all of your controllers in one folder, and views in one folder, and models in one folder and store in....you get it. Which you and I and maybe a few other's know, will not work well when it comes to Large Web Application development.

This is turning into a rant, let me cut to the chase (my colleague noticed this post and wanted me to share some insight):
The Modular Design Pattern is completely doable with ExtJs, and it works very well. You'll just have to write your own library to enforce the pattern while using the ExtJs Framework. I'm using my own library and it has:

1. Made unit testing easy
2. Increase productivity and allow for us to set firm deliverable dates and meet them
3. Allowed 2 people to do the work of 4
4. Highly decoupled code, leaning on event driven nature of Javascript

Just to give my "rant" perspective, I have been developing Web Applications (SAAS, and Corporate Intranet Applications) for 20 years as a contractor ($$$). I've used YUI, DOJO, ExtJs, Backbone, and a few others over that 20 years. I wrote versions of my Modular MVC Design Pattern library for DOJO, ExtJs & BackBone (also for ActionScript, but that's another story).

ExtJs has a very stable framework (with a few exceptions in coding style you'll see if you look at their source) that lends itself well to most design patterns.

So, again, to answer you original question:
"Is it a recommended practice to use a module pattern when developing controllers in ext js?"
My Answer is completely, yes.

=============
Worst Javascript Suggestion, that I keep hearing over and over again:
"Why don't we just do it all in JQuery"

Follow up answer to DanielS comment:

DanielS, I apologize for the delay in my response, I will feed you the steps, as best as I can, piece by piece. After each piece please post a question (if any) and we can continue the conversation.

The way I go about it is to first create a JSON Constructor object that will reflect the layout of my Web Application (this is the Web Applications constructor):

```
{
confiiguration: {
    modules: [
        {
          "config": "modules/HelloWordlModule/config/helloWorldConfig.json"
          "namespace": "Modules.HelloWorldModule.HelloWorld" // Namespace of the modules controller
        }
    ]
}
```

}

I would then create a class (this is where the library starts) that will parse that json object and Ext.require the module by the nameSpace value, then in the callback of the Ext.require statement, I would instantiate the module sending the path to the modules configuration file (found in "config" value) in as a constructor parameter ( Ext.create(Modules.HelloWorldModule.HelloWorld, { configEndpoint: config}); ). Inside the instantiated Module's controller, I would make an ajax request to get the module's JSON configuration (use a store and model to manage the ajax request).

When sending events from the module:
Create a class that is a singleton that extends a Ext.app.Controller. Use that class' instance to trigger events.
example:

```
Ext.define('Modules.EventsController.ModulesEvents', {
  extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
  singleton: true,
  /** @property */
  LOGIN_USER: 'loginUser'
};

Ext.define('Modules.HelloWorldModule.HelloWorld',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
        "Modules.EventsController.ModulesEvents" // requiring singleton, instantiates the class 
    ],

    onUserLogin: function(){
        var modulesEventBus = this.getModulesEventBus();
        if(modulesEventBus){
            modulesEventBus.fireEvent(modulesEventBus.LOGIN_USER, { username: 'jDoe', email: 'jdoe@website.com'});
        }
    },

    getModulesEventBus: function(){
        var eventBus = Modules.EventsController.ModulesEvents;
        if(!eventBus){
            console.log("eventBus is undefined");
        }
        return eventBus;
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you for your inspiring answer.
Can you elaborate on a library to enforce the pattern?
Also, can you suggest a way to fire events from the module without using the framework abilities?

Comment: DanielS, I added a follow up to your comment in the accepted answer. I look forward to your response.

Comment: mhaydendeveloper, I added an implementation of the module pattern. I'd love to hear your comments on it. Also, I'm not sure why did you implement an eventBus in your answer. Ext Js has apllication wide events, so implementing your own event bus seems redundant

Answer (score 0):

DanielS,
The code sample you have added looks like a great start to a nice Web Application, but I think I have a different definition of a Module than what you have here. A Module to me is:

1. a small Javascript application that can run on it's own without requiring any other module
2. The module at it's most basic will have a controller, a model, a store, and a view

That module would then be able to be:

1. Included into the web application dynamically
2. Unit Tested on its own without the complete web application
3. Minified/Obfuscated

In regards to the event bus. I usually use 3 types of event buses.

1. Event Bus for the Library that dynamically loads my Modules (ApplicationEventBus)
2. Event Bus for Module to Module communication (ModulesEventBus)
3. Event Bus for each module for communication amongst that module's own instantiated classes (controller, view, etc.)

This alone is not why I create my own event buses.

1. the CONSTANTS I use in the event bus act as a signature for an event being fired or received. This means, we can listen and fire the event from any given class by referencing that signature.

So this:

```
this.eventBus.fireEvent("loginUser");
this.eventBus.on("loginUser");
```

becomes

```
this.eventBus.fireEvent(this.eventBus.LOGIN_USER);
this.eventBus.on(this.eventBus.LOGIN_USER);
```

1. So if I need to change the value of this.eventBus.LOGIN_USER I will
   only need to update one location rather than many. Which means less
   code to touch, therefore, less likely I will introduce a bug.
2. The events are "namespaced" inside the event bus so less likely to have event naming conflicts with other events being fired.